# Theming options (enable, disable, set to default) are missing. Also, the options on the gear icon on blocks. -Drupal 7

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, block, setting, theming

I am using Drupal 7 in Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

My theming options such as enable, disable, set to default are missing. Already tried clearing the cache, just in case it can help.

Also, the options on the gear icon (settings) located on the top-right corner of blocks are missing.

Any help would be very much appreciated. A lot of thanks. :)

-N

Comment: do the user have all the superadmin permission to configure blocks, views and themes?

Comment: Administer blocks, Administer themes, Administer views must be checked for superadmin

Comment: @Viswanath I would say Administer blocks, Administer themes, Administer views are checked for superadmin. I am now checking for CSS class that might be overwritten. I will just get back to you after some debugging. :) I really appreciate your help. :)

Comment: As promised, I will be back for an update

Sadly, I wasn't able to debug the problem, both CSS and html. So, finally made the decision of retrieving original files from the prod site (where functions are usable) to local. Then, there it worked again.

I really appreciate your response. A lot of thanks. :)

Comment: if its not the permission then you must check what changes in code you have done so that the links stopped working. if you are using in svn or git try to see the difference of files from previous revisions.